# Re-launching the docker container from same state from where it failed?

Tags: docker

I am running some Machine Learning python code in one docker container and suppose it fails due to whatever reason and i want to launch a new container from the same state where the old one left computation of my code?Is there any way to do it?Like can we store the state or something like that and re-run it?

Comment: I guess not. Maybe you should read what’s are the differences between a Docker container and a VM?

Comment: Generally the approaches you'd use to make this work outside Docker will work well in Docker too (break up the job into smaller work units and checkpoint them, for example); Docker doesn't provide any special support here.

Comment: okay will try thanks for hint

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in docker. Containers are isolated from each other. You can start and run multiple containers of the same image but they don't interfere each other. So when you will start a new container, it will be totally a new instance of your application.